# How should a stored proc creation script look like for db2 9.5 w/o compat vector?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

- There's no "ALTER PROCEDURE" or "DROP IF EXISTS". How to make the script run without errors regardless of the proc already exists or not?
- `data studio` and `clp`/`Control Center` have different hints for changing statement terminator
- Multiple overloaded versions of the SP could be created by mistake. Need to drop them all
- There's no built-in SP for dropping other SPs, correct me, if I'm wrong
- compound statements can't execute dynamic SQL, so you need a temporary procedure

all these summarized result a quite heavy script header:

```
--<ScriptOptions statementTerminator="^"/>
--#SET TERMINATOR ^
CREATE PROCEDURE db2inst1.tmp_my_drop_procs()
BEGIN
    DECLARE @STMT VARCHAR(10000);
    FOR v1 AS SELECT SPECIFICNAME from syscat.procedures where PROCSCHEMA = 'DB2INST1' AND PROCNAME = 'CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ARCH'
    DO
        SET @STMT = 'DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE DB2INST1.' ||  SPECIFICNAME;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @STMT;
    END FOR;
END
^
CALL db2inst1.tmp_my_drop_procs()^

DROP PROCEDURE db2inst1.tmp_my_drop_procs^

CREATE PROCEDURE db2inst1.CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ARCH()
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN ATOMIC
-- ...
END
^
```

Comment: Given how rarely stored procedures should be created/updated/dropped, most of the time the admins are creating custom one-off scripts **anyways**.  Which takes care of pretty much all your concerns - they research which ones exist (and/or rewrite/don't care if the db complains about a proc not existing), use a script designed for the tool running it, have to research which procs are actually overloads of a specific one _anyways_, have to write the commands anyways (a `dropStoredProc` procedure sounds abusable), etc....  What actual problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Customer complains our scripts don't run cleanly without errors

Comment: ...Then either they aren't doing enough work on their end, or you don't have enough insight into their systems.  Or you can spend a lot of effort to write a full-on "install script" (ie, a stored proc that uses dynamic SQL to find/delete/maybe create existing procs), and pray they haven't done something funky like stick one in a different library/schema or something.  I was assuming you were in-house, so were largely doing admin work.  Unless you have a _specific_ problem, this is probably too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a continue handler that ignores SQLSTATE '42704' (object not found). Here's an example that I had lying.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_procedure (procschema varchar(128), 
                                 procname   varchar(128))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE tmpstmt VARCHAR(100);
    SET tmpstmt = 'drop procedure ' || procschema || '.' || procname;

    A: BEGIN
        -- Do nothing if drop procedure fails
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42704'
            BEGIN
            END;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE tmpstmt;
    END;
END @
```